# If $f'(x)$ is odd then is $f(x)$ even?

Tags: calculus

I am trying to prove but every proof I encounter can also prove that if $f'(x)$ is even then $f(x)$ is odd and this is not correct ($x^3 + 1$ for example).
Thanks!

Comment: $x^3+1$ is neither odd nor even.  What proofs have you encountered?

Comment: The obvious proof is by integrating $f'$ from $0$ to $x$. On the other hand, when $f'$ is even, you should get $f(x)-f(0)=-\big(f(-x)-f(0)\big)$, which does not imply that $f$ is odd.

Comment: @Henrik $\cos x$ is even.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/357232, when I tried this solution for both cases it succeeded. Im curios what am I doing wrong.. thanks for the comments and solution though! It's really helpful!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $f'(x)$ is odd. Then $f'(-x) = -f'(x)$.

Consider that by the fundamental theorem of calculus, $f(t) - f(0)= \int_{0}^t f'(x)\, dx$. Now let $t \mapsto -t$, and we have

$$f(-t) - f(0) = \int_{0}^{-t} f'(x)\, dx = -\int_{-t}^0 f'(x)\, dx = \int_{-t}^0 f'(-x)\, dx.$$

Substitute $u = -x$, and we get

$$f(-t) - f(0) = -\int_{t}^0 f'(u)\, du = \int_0^t f'(u)\, du.$$

So $f(-t) = f(t)$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $g(x)=f(-x)$, then $g'(x)=[f(-x)]'=-f'(-x)$. Since $f'(x)$ is odd, $f'(x)=-f'(-x)=g'(x)$ and $f'(0)=g'(0)=0$. Thus $f(x)=g(x)=f(-x)$. Thus $f(x)$ is even.