# What extra assumptions are needed to prove $f'(x) \text{ odd } \implies f(x) \text{ even }$?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, solution-verification

Let's say we are trying to prove $f'(x) \text{ odd } \implies f(x) \text{ even }$.

$f'$ odd means

$$f'(x)=-f'(-x)$$

$$\int_0^x f'(x)dx=-\int_0^x f'(-x)dx$$

Now if $g(x)=-f(-x)$ then $g'(x)=f'(-x)$. Hence

$$f(x)-f(0)=-(g(x)-g(0))$$

$$=-[-f(-x)-(-f(0))]$$

$$=f(-x)-f(0)$$

Thus

$f(x)=f(-x)$

Which means $f$ is even.

I'm not sure if this is correct, and even if it is there must be some important implicit assumption being used in the calculations because consider the following case

$$f'(x)=\begin{cases} 1, x\geq 0 \\ -1, x<0 \end{cases}$$

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} x, x\geq 0 \\ c-x, x<0 \end{cases}$$

Then we have

[image]

So we have $f'$ odd, but $f$ is not even.

Is the problem in the derivation the fact that for the function I assumed that $g'(x)=f'(-x)$ at all points including $0$?

Perhaps I should have said

> Now if $g(x)=-f(-x)$ and $g'$ exists for all $x$

Comment: "*consider the following case*" $\,-\,$ That's not differentiable at $x=0$.

Comment: Yes, I figured, but what is the exact specification of the hidden assumption in the analytical derivation at the beginning?

Comment: There is no hidden assumption, it's just that no function $f(x)$ exists such that its derivative has a jump discontinuity. Lookup [Darboux's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)).

Comment: @dxiv Doesn't that result apply to continuous functions only? The picture I drew is of a discontinuous function, and the derivative has a jump discontinuity. Are you saying the picture and example are impossible?

Comment: In contrast, it is certainly not true that $f'(x)$ being even implies that $f(x)$ is odd, unless $f(0)=0$. To get an odd function, one must instead consider $g(x)=f(x)-f(0)$, which has the same (even) derivative as $f$. Adding a constant to an even function still gives an even function, but adding a nonzero constant to an odd function makes the function no longer odd.

Comment: @evianpring A discontinuous function is not differentiable, which contradicts your premise that $f'$ is odd, presumably on $\mathbb R$ since you did not specify a domain.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$f'$ odd implies that $f$ is even](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357215/f-odd-implies-that-f-is-even)

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang I am asking precisely what the assumptions would need to be to obtain the result. And specifically, is it possible for the proof I wrote to be correct under certain assumptions? What assumptions and what step in the proof requires the assumptions?

Comment: Show that the derivative of $x \mapsto f(x)-f(-x)$ is zero.

Comment: Just consolidating and adding to what others have already said, but it should be emphasized again that while the statement is always true (since the usage $f'$ implies differentiable everywhere on some kind of set) your specific proof integrates $f'$ which is invalid. In general it is not true that $\int f' = f + C$ because it is possible for $f'$ to not be integrable.

Answer (score 6):

You don’t need any assumption except that $f$ is differentiable everywhere and the equation holds everywhere, but your proof in particular requires that $f’$ is integrable, which isn’t necessarily true.

For the most general case, consider $g(x) = f(x) - f(-x)$. Then $g’(x) = f’(x) + f’(-x) = 0$. Therefore, $g$ is constant. And $g(0) = 0$. Therefore, $g = 0$, so $f(x) = f(-x)$.

Comment: But the function in my example is integrable, so what part of the proof fails for that example?

Comment: @evianpring Your function $f$ isn’t differentiable everywhere. It’s not even continuous everywhere. You incorrectly state that $f’(0) = 1$, but if $f’$ really were odd, then $f’(0) = 0$ would need to be true. Of course, in fact, $f’(0)$ doesn’t exist at all. So you actually made 2 errors here - you miscalculated $f’$, and the $f’$ you’ve claimed to find isn’t even odd.

Comment: Ok. So if we assume that $f$ is differentiable then the proof of $f'$ odd $\implies$ $f$ even is true?

Comment: @evianpring Yes, as I showed. Your proof requires the additional assumption that $f’$ is integrable - there are some funky counterexamples where this isn’t the case, like $f(x) = \begin{cases} x^2 \cos{\frac{1}{x^2}} & x \neq 0 \\ 0 & x = 0\end{cases}$ where $f’$ exists everywhere and is odd but is not bounded.

Comment: Also, consider the $f'$ in my example. You are correct, it is undefined at $0$. Is the reason that it is not considered odd simply that the relationship $f(x)=-f(-x)$ is not defined for $x=0$. Ie, that relationship has to be true for all $x$ in the domain. So odd functions cannot be undefined anywhere?

Comment: @evianpring The assumption that is needed to make this proof work is that the $f$ is differentiable on all of $\mathbb{R}$ (though there may be a very clever relaxation of this - it seems like continuity everywhere and differentiability almost everywhere will be enough, but proving this isn’t elementary). As for whether the definition of “odd” requires the function to be defined everywhere, I am not sure.

Comment: @evianpring "*if we assume that $f$ is differentiable*" $\,-\,$ That is implicitly assumed in the premise that "$f'(x)$ *is odd*". Something cannot be odd (or even, or whatever) if it is not defined in the first place. You don't need an *additional* assumption that $f$ is differentiable, because you already assumed that $f'$ exists.

Comment: @dxiv Ok, what if we just forget about odd/even and simply define a function $h(x)=1$ for $x>0$ and $h(x)=-1$ for $x<0$. Then we can say that for $x\neq 0$ we have $h(x)=-h(-x)$. $h$ is also integrable. At this point for some interval $[a,x]$ that doesn't include $0$ can we not integrate from $a$ to $x$ to obtain $H(x)-H(a)=-[-H(-x)+H(-a)]=H(-x)-H(-a)$? Ok, this is just some result, nor necessarily interesting. I guess the crucial thing is that $h$ be defined at $0$ so that $H$ is differentiable there.

Comment: @evianpring I don't see how that even relates to the original question. Note that the $h(x)$ you define here can *not* be the derivative of any function, because it does not have the Darboux property on $\mathbb R$. I already pointed that out in my second comment under the main question. I suggest you revisit those comments and the links therein, since this is going circles now.

Comment: @dxiv I'm simply investigating the problem in general. I understood the answer to the original question and your comment about it. When I said "forget about odd/even" in my last comment, that was pretty clearly deviating from the original question. Note that the $h$ I defined above is undefined at $0$. Can this function not be the derivative of some function that is not differentiable at $0$?

Comment: If it can, the result I reached $H(x)=H(-x)+H(a)-H(-a)$ seems to make some sense. If instead we assume that  $h$ is continuous at $0$, then it would be the derivative of some $H$, and the result above would be $H(x)=H(-x)$ for $a=0$. Now, perhaps this next comment is completely wrong but, what if $h$ is continuous at $0$ and then a step function everywhere else such that $h(x)=-h(-x)$. Would we not reach the same result that $H(x)=H(-x)$?

Comment: @evianpring Not sure what you mean there, and it doesn't sound related to the original question any longer. All I can say is that if you have a different question to ask, then post it as a new question.