# Spivak: Let $\alpha(x)=\int_0^x (1+t^2)^{-1} dt$. Prove that $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} \alpha(x)=-\lim\limits_{x\to -\infty} \alpha(x)$.

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, derivatives, proof-explanation

Spivak, Ch. 15, "Trigonometric Functions"

> 29. (a) Let $\alpha(x)=\int_0^x (1+t^2)^{-1} dt$. Prove that $\alpha$ is odd and increasing, and that $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} \alpha(x)$
>     and $\lim\limits_{x\to -\infty} \alpha(x)$ both exist, and are
>     negatives of each other. If we define $\pi=2\lim\limits_{x\to
>      \infty}\alpha(x)$, then $\alpha^{-1}$ is defined on $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$

$\frac{1}{1+t^2}$ is differentiable and even.

The FTC1 tells us that $\alpha'(x)=(1+x^2)^{-1}>0$ for all $x$. Thus $\alpha$ is increasing.

Also, $\alpha$ is odd based on the following result

$$f \text{ differentiable and }f' \text{ even } \implies f\text{ odd}$$

[which is proved in one of the answers to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4497781/what-extra-assumptions-are-needed-to-prove-fx-text-odd-implies-fx-te/4497792?noredirect=1#comment9437824_4497792).

**My question concerns proving that $$\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} \alpha(x)=-\lim\limits_{x\to -\infty} \alpha(x)$$**

Consider the first of the limits

$$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \alpha(x)=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\int_0^x (1+t^2)^{-1} dt=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\left [\int_0^1 (1+t^2)^{-1} dt+\int_1^x (1+t^2)^{-1} dt\right ]$$

$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \int_1^x (1+t^2)^{-1} dt$ exists because

$$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\int_1^x (t^2)^{-1} dt=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \left . -t^{-1} \right |_1^x= \lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\left [-\frac{1}{x}+1\right ]=1$$

and

$$0<\frac{1}{1+t^2}<\frac{1}{t^2}$$

$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \int_0^1 (1+t^2)^{-1} dt$ exists because $(1+t^2)^{-1}$ is continuous and hence integrable on $[0,1]$.

Now, the second limit is the one that I am a bit confused about.

$$\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty} \alpha(x)=\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}\int_0^x (1+t^2)^{-1} dt=\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}\left [-\int_x^0 (1+t^2)^{-1} dt\right ]=\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}\left [\int_x^{-1} (1+t^2)^{-1} dt+\int_{-1}^0 (1+t^2)^{-1} dt\right ]$$

Intuitively, since $(1+t^2)^{-1}$ is even, we know that

$$\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}\int_x^{-1} (1+t^2)^{-1} dt=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\int_1^x (1+t^2)^{-1} dt$$

$$\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}\int_{-1}^0 (1+t^2)^{-1} dt=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\int_0^1 (1+t^2)^{-1} dt$$

Which means we are done.

But how do we actually show this result formally?

Note that so far in this book, as far as integration is concerned only the definition of integral, the fundamental theorem of calculus, and some trigonometric integrals have been introduced. No fancy techniques to compute the integrals from the question above.

Comment: I'm not sure why your proof is so long. Every odd function (in particular $\alpha$), satisfies the equality in the title, provided the limits exist. Which step are you looking to justify formally?

Comment: You could just calculate the proper integral $\alpha(x)$ and get $\alpha(x) = \arctan(x)$. Taking limits gives the result.

Comment: @Gargantuar consider the final paragraph in OP's question. Just for context: the purpose of this problem is to *define* $\arctan$ by this integral (hence the suggestive notation $\alpha$), and use this integral to define $\pi$, and develop trigonometry from there. This just shows an alternative (and rapid) approach to defining the trigonometric functions.

Comment: @peek-a-boo precisely that result, namely that the integral of an odd function from 0 to $x$ is the same as the integral from $-x$ to 0. How do we prove that? I don't recall having proved that in the chapter on Integrals. $\int_{-x}^0 f=-\int_0^{-x} f$, but this seemingly doesn't lead anywhere.

Comment: You're integrating an even function (if $g:[-a,a]\to\Bbb{R}$ is RIemann integrable and even, then $G:[-a,a]\to\Bbb{R}$, $G(x)=\int_0^xg$ is odd). And didn't you say this is already justified in your linked post?

Comment: @peek-a-boo AFAIK, this standard result is derived by the [inverse function rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_rule) and then using the fundamental theorem of calculus to get the integral with result $\arctan$.

Comment: @Gargantuar yes I'm aware of that. THe 'usual' approaches start by first defining $\sin,\cos$ then $\tan=\frac{\sin}{\cos}$, showing $\tan$ has certain monotonicty properties and differentiability then IFT as you say to compute $\arctan'$. I'm saying that the purpose of this problem is to introduce trigonometry differently (but ultimately equivalently). Step 1 is to define $\alpha$, which will turn out to be $\arctan$, and then proceed from there.

Comment: look at problem 16 in chapter 13. It asks you to prove (from the definitions using upper and lower sums) that $\int_{ca}^{cb}f(t)\,dt=c\int_a^bf(ct)\,dt$. Using this with $c=-1$ gives you what you want. This is a special case of the more general change of variables theorem you'll see later on in C19. In any case, it's a good exercise to be able to prove this special case by-hand. Once you do so, this question becomes very simple.

Comment: I recall that exercise now. You are right though, given that I proved that $\alpha$ is odd, I have $\alpha(x)=\int_0^x f(t)dt=-\alpha(-x)=-\int_0^{-x} f(t)dt$ Taking the limit when $x\to \infty$ gives the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\alpha(x) &=\int_{0}^{x}\left(1+t^{2}\right)^{-1} d t \\
&=\left[\arctan t\right]_{0}^{x} \\
&=\arctan  x \\
\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} \alpha(x)&=\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} \arctan  x=\frac{\pi}{2} \\
\lim _{x \rightarrow-\infty} \alpha(x)&=\lim _{x \rightarrow-\infty} \arctan x=-\frac{\pi}{2} \\
\therefore \lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} \alpha(x)&=-\lim _{x \rightarrow-\infty} \alpha(x)
\end{aligned}
$$